# Oops! I think I broke my work environment (nvm, npm, and node w/ angular). :(

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, nvm

It has been a long time since I programmed using my personal computer. I usually use a work computer. However, yesterday I decided to start working on a new pet project. Well, I went to set up the website in my Vagrant using VirtualBox, and now nvm, npm, and node are all messed up.

Every time I try to run npm install to set-up the node_module in my project, I get this error:

```
/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.32/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:27
        console.error(`a bug known to break npm. Please update to at least ${r
                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.32/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.32/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:92:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

No matter what I try to do in npm (upgrade it, install, delete, uninstall, etc) it just throws this error.

Could somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of npm you have is not supported on Node v0.10.32. In fact Node v0.10 itself is not supported either and projects are actively dropping support it. Most dependencies will want node v4+ these days.

The version of npm you have installed will be available in the VM:

```
cat /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.32/lib/node_modules/npm/package.json
```

You will need to manually extract one of the [v2](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v2.15.12) or possibly even a [v1](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v1.4.29) npm release over the files in `/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.32/lib/node_modules/npm`.

Removing and setting up your `nvm` `v0.10.32` environment again should also take `npm` back to a working release.

I would guess your Vagrant build does something like an `npm install -g npm` which would have worked at some stage but now installs the latest, incompatible version.

Use `npm install -g npm@2` to stick to a v2.x release

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out! I upgraded nvm to version 8.0.0, which upgraded my npm and node versions. Now everything is working great there!